# Is it possible to parse JSON and convert it to the GQLAchemy model object?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've installed GQLAchemy using `pip install gqlalchemy`. Now I want to convert a dictionary object into the appropriate GraphObject. Is it possible to parse JSON and convert it to the GQLAchemy model object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each `GraphObject`, base class for e.g. `Path` has `parse_obj` method that takes JSON is a specific format and returns and instance of that object.